# How to highlight/detect unique word in Sublimetext 2

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimelinter, ox

I found a plugin ([sublimelinter](http://www.sublimelinter.com)) for this task but it is for specific languages.

Do you know a way to highlight/detect unique word in Sublime Text **for all programming languages** ?

To be clear I'm looking for a way to detect unused variable via a plugin wich detect unique word in a code since a unique word is generally also unused (It is not totally true but still it is not a problem if it wrongly detects few words such as "static","serial" and so on for c++. Ideally I should be able to list words to exclude).

Important  : I do not want a solution in which I have to compile my code.

Comment: Seems like a lofty goal for a text editor. You can also compile your code with `-Wunused-variable`.

Comment: thanks for the compilation trick but I"m looking for an answer for a text editor. It will help me a lot to clean my code at "writting" time.

Comment: Text editors are just that: programs that *edit* text. If it doesn't compile the code, it can't tell you what's being used and, thereby, what's **not** being used. Typically these utilities are available for IDEs, but I haven't seen one for a text editor.

Comment: You'll have to use the `clang` plugin which basically just runs your code against the `clang` compiler anytime you make a change and then marks lines with problems.

Comment: Thanks but I do not want to compile the code, in fact it is not a c++ code but a very similar programming language (ox). So I look for a way to identify unique word in my code, since if it is unique it is unused.

Comment: @Malick if you're not using C++, then **don't tag the question C++**. Otherwise you get answers that aren't useful, and annoy the hell out of other users.

Comment: sorry and thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 2):

There is plugin `SublimeClang`. It provides auto complete suggestions and error / warning reporting.

Comment: Sorry I edited my question to add details because it is not for only c++.